# change position of td in a row

Tags: html, css

Im looking for a way to change the placement of two td in one tr.
So the switch positions. The left one should be on the right side and vice versa.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>left cell, but i should be on the right side</td>
        <td>right cell, and i want to be on the left side</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I tried to float them left and right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```css
* {margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none;}
table {width: 100%;}
tr:first-child {display: block; overflow: hidden; width: 100%;}
td {float: right; width: 50%;}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>left cell, but i should be on the right side</td>
    <td>right cell, and i want to be on the left side</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Just use the style attribute

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="float:right; display:block;">left cell, but i should be on the right side</td>
        <td style="float:left; display:block;">right cell, and i want to be on the left side</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: why recommending inline styling when the same can be achieved with proper css selectors? inline styling is long considered bad practice

Comment: @Luca It was honestly just for the demonstration of how float would work (as OP claimed to have tried and failed). Both selectors and inline would work, and if OP wanted to put it in a style-sheet then that's up to him. I take your point though that you should always separate markup from styling. This was also before OP made the comment that he can't edit the html.